# Returning value from ThreadPool Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

Why does the following code ALWAYS return `False` in `obj`. I have ensured that `SomeBoolReturningFunc` is returning `True`.

```
Dim obj As Object = False
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state)
                                  state = SomeBoolReturningFunc()
                             End Sub,
                             obj)

'Keep waiting till queued thread completes
Return obj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recap what happens here:

1. The anonymous function recieves the object you stored in `obj` as argument `state`.
2. You overwrite the local variable `state` with the return value of `SomeBoolReturningFunc`.
3. Your original object is not changed.

To have it work the way you expect it, the anonymous method would have to use a `ByRef` parameter and the `QueueUserWorkItem` would have to support it.

To solve your issue, you could use a mutable wrapper class:

```
Class Wrapper
    Public Value as Boolean
End Class

Dim obj = new Wrapper()
obj.Value = False
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state)
                                  obj.Value=SomeBoolReturningFunc()
                             End Sub, obj)
```

`obj.Value` will now be changed to `True` when the anonymous function gets executed.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is precisely what I ended up with. This also brings up another question that I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064027/is-there-a-built-in-generic-class-for-this-in-net. Please have a look.