# Is there a built-in generic class for this in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics

Is there a class that is precisely equal to this class?

```
Class X(Of T)
    Public value As T
End Class
```

Note that neither `Nullable(Of T)` nor `Tuple(Of T)` are equal to this class because they do not allow you to set the member value. The class should have the following properties:

1. When passed as parameter, any changes made by the called method should affect the sent object, i.e. it should not create a copy of object as it does for intrinsic types.
2. Should allow setting the member `value` to a value using syntax `x.value = <some value>` where x is an object of X.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of it, but just in case you aren't, or someone else who stumbles across this page in the future isn't.... You are familiar with the `ByRef` modifier keyword, right?

Comment: Yes, I am. But it doesn't work in my case. I need to pass the variable to QueueUserWorkItem's callback delegate, which happens to have the definition 'Delegate Sub WaitCallback(state As Object)'. So sending in ByRef is not an option. I'm going modify the variable within the callback function and then check its value in the main thread after the callback completes. Even sending an object (which is a ref type) is not a solution, becuz assigning a value to state variable in the callback function will leave the original object unchanged. So I need a REF type that wraps a VAL type in it.

Comment: Ok.  You sounded like someone who knew what you were doing, but I felt the need to mention it.  Carry on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a conclusive answer, but i'll give it a go.

I personally have not seen this type of class before. Even the documentation on generics shows an example class similar to yours being created and used in the examples:

[msdn generics in the .net framework.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx)

Here's the example:

```
Public Class Generic(Of T)
    Public Field As T

End Class

....

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim g As New Generic(Of String)
    g.Field = "A string" 
    '...
    Console.WriteLine("Generic.Field           = ""{0}""", g.Field)
    Console.WriteLine("Generic.Field.GetType() = {0}", g.Field.GetType().FullName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep. That looks like some evidence. Thanks. I'll wait for some more input before marking "No" as the answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I would also like to know about this too.

Answer (score 1):

I've sometimes created such a class, almost verbatim, although I called the class `Holder<T>` and the field `Value`; there are two nice usage cases for such a class:

- Given a collection of `Holder<someValueType>`, it's possible to perform convenient in-place modifications of the contents of the collection.  For example, given a `List<Holder<Point>>`, one can say `MyList[3].Value.X += 5;`.
- If `T` is of a type that permits atomic operations, one may perform thread-safe atomic operations on the contents of a collection of `Holder<T>` even if the collection is not threadsafe.  For example, in one scenario where I knew in advance all of the keys I'd need for a dictionary, I created a `Dictionary<String, Holder<Integer>>` and then could have multiple threads use `Interlocked.Increment` to count how many times each of those strings appeared.  Even though `Dictionary` was not thread-safe, the program was thread-safe without locking because the set of `Holder<Integer>` items stored in the dictionary never had to change.

If you want to use a built-in type, there is one that would work: a `T[]` with size one.  The main disadvantage of that type is that there's nothing inherent in the type which guarantees that element zero will actually exist (i.e. that it won't be an empty array).